# Hi, am trying to create 3d model View similar to 3dtuning app

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d-model

I am trying to create 3d model View in UNITY 3d similar to 3d tuning app. If any reference course or Video please help me. Really appreciate the help. Please check attached images

Comment: Welcome! fyi resource recommendation questions (like questions asking for a reference course/tutorial) are off-topic here. Also, you haven't shown any work. You only included an image with no specifics. You'd need to edit your question to show what you've done, along with specific issues/errors/etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.